# How do I change the base of D3's symlog

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, visualization, scale

I'm currently using d3.scaleSymlog to plot some data. Unlike d3.scaleLog, d3.scaleSymlog doesn't produce a scale that allows me to set the base like this d3.scaleSymlog().base(2). So, I'm wondering if anyone has had any luck changing the  base of symlog or if anyone has any ideas. I've tried a couple of things, but I'm not sure if they make sense. Below you can see what I've tried.

**Context:**

Per the original paper listed in the d3 docs Symlog is defined as:
`symlog10 = Math.sign(x) * Math.log10(1 + Math.abs(x/c))`
In my case, c is always 1, so it doesn't affect anything.

Per d3:   `symlog = Math.sign(x) * Math.log1p(Math.abs(x / c))` where
Math.log1p(x) is the same as Math.log(1+x)
so symlog = Math.sign(x) * Math.log(1 + Math.abs(x/c))

So, it looks like Symlog defined by d3 just changes the base to the natural log using the change  of base formula:

`Math.log(1 + Math.abs(x/c)) === Math.log10(1 + Math.abs(x/c)) / Math.log10(Math.E)`

So, it follows that Symlog follows the same change of base rules, so if I wanted to change d3’s symblog to a base of 2, I can do:

symlog2 = Symlog(x)/Math.Log(2)

So, I  tried 2 things.

1.

```
const scalingFactor = (1 / Math.log(base));
const scale = scaleSymlog().domain([domain[0] ** scalingFactor], domain[1] ** scalingFactor])
      .range(range);

// Use with value
scale(value ** scalingFactor)
```

Above I scale my value and domain because of the log rule log(x^p) = p*log(x). Since what I want is symlog(x)/Math.log(base) it seems like this rule is useful because symlog(x^(1/Math.log(base)) = (1/Math.log(base) * symlog(x) = symlog(x)/Math.log(base).

2.

```
function symlog(x, base, c) {
  return (Math.sign(x) * Math.log1p(Math.abs(x / c))) / Math.log(base);
}
const scale = scaleLinear()
      .domain([symlog(domain[0], base, constant), symlog(domain[1], base, constant)])
      .range(range);

// Use with value
scale(symlog(value, base, 1))
```

If a linear scale is y = mx + b, using a linear scale with x passed in transformed with symlog should give us a symlog transformation since x will be now be symlog(x), and the same is true for sym log of all bases e.g.,   Y = m * Symlog2(x) + b, which I think is ultimately how the transform from the domain to range is applied.

Weirdly, this one actually gives me the same result as calling the symlog scale normally
`scaleSymlog().domain(domain).range(range)`